# How to verify and remove digital signature using openssl

Tags: openssl

I want to verify and remove signature after that in xml file. My file is not encrypted just signed. That is i want to get a file containing just data without signature after successful verifying as an output.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Please be sure to show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered